# Derive unique denominators from number

Tags: special-functions

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a set of numbers ('target numbers') through a function and get out a number that when queried against in some way (with a 'target' number as all/part of the query) would return a true / false as to whether or not that number exists in the output of the function.  Tough for me to verbalize so I'll show an example

say my list of numbers is
ListOfNumbers = [1,5,100,46736,3]

Can I run it through some function f(ListOfNumbers) = outputNumber

So that I can then run another function f(queryNumber,outputNumber) = true/false

also, the outputNumber (or one of the functions) has to be such that if I did something like this..

f(46736,outputNumber) = true
but (23368,outputNumber) = false  <-- it's a factor of 46736 but should not return true, only the numbers in the list return true.

Also, if it's not possible with one function, I wonder if it is possible with a couple different functions and if you get two or 'x' trues and no falses it is in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you care about the members of the list and not their order or possible repeats.

Consider the function $f(S)=\sum_{s \in S}2^s.$ That is in some sense the most efficient possible function which gives a unique output to every set of numbers. Every positive integer is a possible output.

The function $g(y,B)=\lfloor \frac{B}{2^y}  \rfloor \bmod 2$ will output $1$ or $0$ according as $y \in S$ or $y \notin S$ for the unique set with $f(S)=B.$ Of course the formula given for $g(y,B)$ amounts to the $y$th bit of the binary expansion of $B.$

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  I'm not a math person by trade so It'll take me a little to apply that to by problem but I do believe I understand what you are saying.... with the exception of the 'yth bit of the binary exapansion' comment.  Did you mention that because it can be a huge number ?  Also, yes, you are right I don't care about the order or possible repeats.

Comment: and also, can you get the entire original list back out with another function ?

Comment: I mentioned it because I wrote $g$ in a mysterious way but it is pretty simple. For $S=\{3,5,10\}$ we have $f(s)=2^3+2^5+2^{10})=1000010100$ when written in base $2.$ We see that $S$ was a set of size $3$ and can count off the members.

Comment: One can always find a function that fits a given sequence as well as the target number you will use, or *not* as well as the target number you will use.  Thus you must have some cost or penalty function to select among functions that fit the given "training set."  In general, and for excellent theoretical reasons (Ockham's razor), "simple" model fits to the given data should be preferred over "complex" model fits.

Comment: ok, thank you all for the help.  It's all over my head but I'll try and break it down and apply it to my issue.  Thanks again